# How can I create a condition with OR and AND in HAPROXY

Tags: haproxy

I need to create a silent drop rule.
If packet not from example_lan_allowed to path_beg /api/ or path_beg /swagger-ui/ has been received by HAPROXY, it should be passed, but other packets to req_example not from example_lan_allowed should be blocked.

```
acl req_example req.hdr(host) -i example.com
acl example_path path_beg /api/
acl example_path path_beg /swagger-ui/
acl example_lan_allowed hdr_ip(X-Forwarded-For) -f /etc/haproxy/whitelist.ips


http-request silent-drop if req_swift !swift_path !ffb_lan_allowed -- This not work for some reason. /swagger-ui/ packet are droped
```